# java.io.FileNameFilter

Tags: java, file, io

```
interface FilenameFilter {
    boolean accept(File dir, String name);
}
```

As Far as I know FileNameFilter is used to select files based on specific pattern or extension. For that 'String name' alone is enough. Why the 'File dir' parameter is required?
Is there any specific reason or use for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FilenameFilter` - just interface.

You can write your own implementation that will be care about `dir` where file placed

Answer (score 2):

The **dir** object is the parent directory of the file, and **name** is the name of the file.

---

[**accept**](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/AbstractFileFilter.html)

```
public boolean accept(File dir,
                      String name)
```

Checks to see if the File should be accepted by this filter.

**Specified by:**

accept in interface FilenameFilter

**Specified by:**
accept in interface IOFileFilter

**Parameters:**

`dir` - the directory File to check

`name` - the filename within the directory to check

**Returns:**

true if this file matches the test

---

Comment: Is there any use of knowing parent of the file?

Comment: sure , the `name` variable is just the name of the file , so you need the diractory to know the full path

Comment: So you say the implementer may have some need to check whether the file is in a particular directory ,like that?

Comment: You need to know that the first thing is the `dir` in which you will search on the `filename`, so we specify the dir first like this :` File dir = new File("d:\\");' , then you get the files

Answer (score 0):

Check the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html#accept%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
Parameters:
dir - the directory in which the file was found.
name - the name of the file.
```

Answer (score 0):

[Interface FilenameFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html)

> Instances of classes that implement this interface are used to filter
>   filenames. These instances are used to filter directory listings in
>   the list method of class File, and by the Abstract Window Toolkit's
>   file dialog component.